# Safari driver starts launching and immediately stops on mac

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, safaridriver

Getting below error on safari browser:

```
0.016s] [safaridriver.client] Connecting to SafariDriver browser extension...
[  0.027s] [safaridriver.client] This will fail if you have not installed the latest SafariDriver extension from
http://selenium-release.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
[  0.027s] [safaridriver.client] Extension logs may be viewed by clicking the Selenium [✓] button on the Safari toolbar
```

On console window:

```
The browser selected is..Safari
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:11 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer start
INFO: Server started on port 28320
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:11 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Launching Safari
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:11 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor start
INFO: Waiting for SafariDriver to connect
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping Safari
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverServer stop
INFO: Stopping server
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutting down
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Stopping server
Mar 01, 2018 3:22:21 AM org.openqa.selenium.safari.SafariDriverCommandExecutor stop
INFO: Shutdown complete
```

Answer (score 0):

A lot of times, it's because the developer option to allow remote automation isn't clicked. In safari, you can access this by clicking 'preferences' -> advanced. At the bottom it says 'show Developer Menu in Menu Bar.' Click that. Then in the newly appeared develop tab click on 'Allow Remote Automate' towards the bottom of the list. If this doesn't run it, post your code and we can take a more thorough look.